# jQuery Loop Function doesn't appear to be working

Tags: jquery

I'm having a problem with a `div` that fades into the page on slide 12 of an HTML/jQuery presentation.

When running the below code the `div` will fade in but will not follow the function called loop and repeat itself. It should fade to 50% opacity and back to 100% in a continuous loop.

I'm fairly confident the issue is with my syntax, but I've had no luck yet.

jQuery:

```
// if slide 12
if (index == 11) {
    $("#prev").show();
    $("#next").show();
    $("#p12-1").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
        function loop() {
            $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
                $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
            });
        };
    });
    createParticles($("#main").offset().left + 200, $("#main").offset().top + 100, 4000);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="main-slide main-slide-12" style="display:none;">
<div id="p12-1" style="display:none;"><img src="images/p12-1.png" /></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="p12-2"><img src="images/p12-2.png" /></div>
<div style="display:none;" id="p12-3"><img src="images/p12-3.png" /></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
$("#p12-1").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    function loop() {
        $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
            $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
        });
    };
});
```

to:

```
$("#p12-1").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    (function loop() {
        $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
            $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
        });
    }());
});
```

**Little update**:

In general it is not needed to queue animations on the same elements using the oncomplete-callback. This said, you could also use code like this, with the same effect (note that you could chain as many animations and delays as you want, and only use `fade` as the last on-complete callback to start over):

```
(function fade () {
  $('#p12-1')
  .delay(2000)
  .fadeIn('slow')
  .delay(2000)
  .fadeOut('slow', fade);
}());
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TPBFt/

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
$("#p12-1").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    function loop() {
        $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
            $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
        });
    };
});
```

with

```
$("#p12-1").delay(2000).fadeIn("slow", function() {
    function loop() {
        $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 0.5, function ()  {
            $("#p12-1").delay(200).fadeTo("slow", 1, loop);
        });
    }
    loop();
});
```

I didn't use a function expression like @Yoshi did since AFAIK some browser do not like named function expressions.